# Python: Print next x lines from text file when hitting string

Tags: python, linux

The situation is as follows:

I have a .txt file with results of several nslookups.

I want to loop tru the file and everytime it hits the string "Non-authoritative answer:" the scripts has to print the following 8 lines *from* that position. If it works I shoud get all the positive results in my screen :).

First I had the following code:

```
#!/bin/usr/python

file = open('/tmp/results_nslookup.txt', 'r')
f = file.readlines()

for positives in f:
        if 'Authoritative answers can be found from:' in positives:
                print positives
file.close()
```

But that only printed "Authoritative answers can be found from:" the times it was in the .txt.

The code what I have now:

```
#!/bin/usr/python

file = open('/tmp/results_nslookup.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

i = lines.index('Non-authoritative answer:\n')

for line in lines[i-0:i+9]:
        print line,

file.close()
```

But when I run it, it prints the first result nicely to my screen but does not print the other positve results.

p.s. I am aware of socket.gethostbyname("foobar.baz") but first I want to solve this basic problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is what `grep` was made for, in particular the `-A` option: `grep -A8 'Non-authoritative answer:' /tmp/results_nslookup.txt`

Comment: Or a simple `awk` one-liner: `awk 'count-->0;/Non-authoritative answer:/{count=8;print}' /tmp/results_nslookup.txt`

Comment: @Kevin I think you should have made that an answer.  Of course, I have this rebellious streak for lateral answers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the file as an iterator, then print the next 8 lines every time you find your sentence:

```
with open('/tmp/results_nslookup.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'Non-authoritative answer:\n':
            for i in range(8):
                print(next(lines).strip())
```

Each time you use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the file object (or loop over it in a `for` loop), it'll return the next line in that file, until you've read the last line.

Instead of the `range(8)` for loop, I'd actually use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('/tmp/results_nslookup.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'Non-authoritative answer:\n':
            print(''.join(islice(f, 8)))
```

Comment: how to print the line which has "Non-authoriative answer" as well?

Comment: @Shashi just add `print(line)` as the first statement inside the `if line ==` test.

Answer (score 4):

```
file = open('/tmp/results_nslookup.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if line=='Non-authoritative answer:\n':
        for _ in range(8):
            print file.next()
```

By the way: don't ever use the name `file` for a variable because it is the name of a built-in function.

Comment: how to print the line which has "Non-authoriative answer" as well?

Comment: @Shasi: just put "print(line)" before the for loop. (But that will always print that fixed text.) You may also want to print (file.next())[:-1] instead, e.g. strip the newline to avoid printing double newlines

Comment: Thank you, did the same yesterday :-)